# GIT : Multiple Jira ticket in one feature branch

Tags: git, jira

Generally for each Jira ticket example: `edw-123`, I create a feature branch as `feature/edw-123` and I can see in the Jira ticket gets updated as below

[image]

I have 2 Jira tickets to work on example `edw-222 & edw-333`, How can I create a feature/branch with both tickets in one, so that both Jira tickets are updated or at least have both the ticket mentioned

Comment: Put the ticket number in the commit message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a branch with both names in it (`edw-123-edw-333`), each JIRA ticket will list it so you'll be able to see the branch from both pages.

Similarly, **if** you want each commit to be present in both commits list, be sure to have these ticket numbers (both) in each commit message.